# OpenSSL hangs while creating an CSR (MSys2)

Tags: openssl, freeze, csr, msys2

I'm trying to create a request with the following OpenSSL v1.0.2 command under MSys2 Windows 7 environment: `$ openssl req -out ios.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ios-private.key`

I'm getting the following output and the process freezes after that:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
................................................................................    .....................................................................+++
................................................................................    ..............................................+++
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Hmm, this seem to work, but only under plain MSys2 shell, not under the MINGW64 version.

Comment: Simply running it in CMD (instead of Git-Bash) worked for me!